# Add a Worksheet using Zend to a Google Spreadsheet in PHP

Tags: google-sheets, zend-framework, worksheet

How do I add a worksheet to a Google docs spreadsheet using Zend?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. Solution will follow.

Answer (score 1):

This one is not very easy to figure out, here is the code that worked for me (thanks to this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googledata2/) and [Zend Framework Quick Reference](http://zfdoc.hafees.com/))

```
// Connection & spreadsheet API
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('you@there.com', 'sunshine-', Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
$service = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);

// Get worksheet feed
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey('your spreadsheet key');
$feed = $service->getWorksheetFeed($query);

// Create new worksheet structure
$newWorksheet = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_WorksheetEntry();
$newWorksheet->setTitle(new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Title("My Brillant New Worsheet", null));
$newWorksheet->setRowCount(new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_Extension_RowCount(10));
$newWorksheet->setColumnCount(new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_Extension_ColCount(10));

// Add new worksheet to worksheets feed
$service->insertEntry($newWorksheet->saveXML(), $feed->getLink('self')->getHref());
```

Comment: very useful. But do you know how to use the [authsub](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18013564/430112)