# get Google client using access token

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-sheets-api, google-api-client, zend-gdata

I already stored the access and refresh token in my database. I want get the google client using that. I don't know how to use it in below example

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('you@there.com', 'password', Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
$service = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);

// Get worksheet feed
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey('your spreadsheet key');
$feed = $spreadsheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query);
```

I want replace email and password with access token. Someone help me how to do that. I tried below. but I got only exception

> Caught exception: Expected response code 200, got 401

and 
Stateless token expired

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient('ya29.XXXXXXX');
```

Another try,

```
$client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient();
$session_token =Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken('ya29.XXXXXXX',$client);
$client->setAuthSubToken($sessionToken);
```

> Caught exception: Token upgrade failed. Reason:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing things up.

ClientLogin and AuthSub are different authentication APIs (both deprecated).
The ClientLogin token expires after two weeks or earlier (see: https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#clientlogin_expire). You can use the token as long as it does not expire by calling the setter `setClientLoginToken` of `Zend_Gdata_HttpClient`.

### Example:

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('email@example.com', 'password', Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
$token = $client->getClientLoginToken();
//Save to DB / in session / whatever
$client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient();
$client->setClientLoginToken($token);
//Do stuff
```

You can also cache the whole HttpClient object with Zend_Cache.

AuthSub or OAuth 2.0 (better, but no classes provided by ZF) is maybe better for your needs, because the tokens do not expire (AuthSub) or can be refreshed (OAuth2)

### Docs

AuthSub:

- ZF Docs > http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.gdata.authsub.html
- Revoke unlimited token >
  https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub?hl=de#AuthSubRevokeToken

OAuth2:

- Refresh tokens > https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer?hl=de#refresh